# Simulating classes in scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm writing code to simulate classes:

```
(define (className)
  (define value 1)
  (define (obj arg1)                    ;constructor
    (define (increment)
      ((+ value 1)))
    (define (get)
      (value))
    (if (equal? arg1 "increment")
        (increment)
        (get)))
  obj)

(define a className)
(display a) ;returns #<procedure className ()>
(display (a "get")) ;trying to call get procedure
```

and I am getting `ERROR: Wrong number of arguments to #<procedure className ()>`. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: This is not simulating. It is doing your own object system with closures. I recommend DrRacket as a nice IDE that does your parenthesis balancing for you and which also has damn good debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems - some unnecessary parenthesis, some  missing parenthesis and the fact that the `increment` procedure is not really mutating the `value` variable. Here, this should fix it:

```
(define (className)
  (define value 1)
  (define (obj arg1)
    (define (increment)
      (set! value (+ value 1)))
    (define (get)
      value)
    (if (equal? arg1 "increment")
        (increment)
        (get)))
  obj)
```

Let's see if it works:

```
(define a (className))

(display a)
=> #<procedure:obj>

(display (a "get"))
=> 1

(a "increment")
(display (a "get"))
=> 2
```

Comment: You're welcome! and use a good IDE, with syntax highlighting - the parenthesis will disappear after a while ;)